# нужен ли venv при использовании Docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask

Начал осваивать flask и параллельно хочу начать ковырять Docker, во всех мануалах (flask/django) рекомуендуют venv для развёртки. Если есть Docker, то на кой нужно использовать лишнее??/

Comment: В данном случае лишнее - это докер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Virualenv` - явно лишнее. Ведь всё уже прописано в `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM python:3.6.3-alpine3.6

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN apk --update add --virtual .base build-base && \
    apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    rm requirements.txt && \
    apk del .base && \
    adduser -D -S -u 1000 -G users -h /home/app app && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/man /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
    /var/cache/apk/* /var/log/* ~/.cache

COPY . /home/app/
RUN chmod +x /home/app/app.py && \
    chown -R app:users /home/app

USER app
WORKDIR /home/app

CMD python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --with-threads
```